# Securing your server from the process of collecting data from insecure machines

Tags: mysql, security, database-connection, raspberry-pi

I am using multiple (~30) Raspberry Pi to collect field data and want to send this data to my (MYSQL) server.  What are the best practices to secure my server as much as possible?

Should I have the client connect to an intermediary like PHP/Java that checks a database of usernames+passwords with rate limiting etc,

or use fail2ban and connect directly to the mysql server?

Comment: Is it that you have 1 centralized mysql server somewhere and raspberries are sending data to it? So then which ones do you want to make secure: the mysql server? or the raspberry pi's?

Comment: This http://www.greensql.com/content/mysql-security-best-practices-hardening-mysql-tips can be a good start anyways.

Comment: And this one http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3958/risk-of-configuring-mysql-for-remote-access-with-a-dynamic-ip-address